# laravel Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i cant access my admin_table i know i have and problem on my route on the admin_table please help me on my route   **Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**

my admin_table.blade

```
@foreach ($users as $positions)
    @foreach ($positions->admins as $position )
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $position->id}}</td>
            <td>{{ $position->first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $position->last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $position->contact}}</td>
            <td>{{ $position->departments->department}}</td>
            <td>{{ $position->schoolpositions->school_position}}</td>
            <td>{{ $position->email}}</td>
            <th> <a href="{{action('DashboardController@edit',$position['id' =>$position->id])}} " class="btn btn-success">Edit </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    @endforeach

    </tr>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
@endforeach
</table>
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/admin_table', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::put('/admin_table/{id}', 'DashboardController@store');
Route::get('/admin_table', 'DashboardController@show');
Route::get('/teacher_editform/{id}', 'DashboardController@edit');
Route::put('/teacher_editform/{id}', 'DashboardController@update')->name('teacheradminpage.teacher_tableform.teacher_editform');
```

this is my controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $departments =  Department::find($id);
    $users =  Schoolposition::find($id);
    $students =  Student::find($id);
    $admins =  Admin::find($id);
    return view('teacheradminpage.teacher_tableform.teacher_editform', compact('departments','users','students','admins', 'id', 'id', 'id', 'id'));
}
```

Comment: Where did you pass `$position` to blade? Also why `id,id,id,id` 4 times? One time is enough.

Comment: `<a href="{{action('DashboardController@edit',$position['id' =>$position->id])}}` in here

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end. ___It also easily show layout errors___

Comment: how do u get `$postion->admin`? Do u have relationship between these variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you put an extra `$position` before the array. Your route should be

```
<a href="{{action('DashboardController@edit',['id' =>$position->id])}} " class="btn btn-success">Edit </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got several issues in this code that probably need attention.  The main issue with the `position` error, seems to be that you've got a circular path to get that `$position` in your `anchor` tab within the loop.

This section is likely not creating what you want:

```
@foreach ($users as $positions)

     @foreach ($positions->admins as $position )
```

This is roughly saying - take my collection of users and make a new collection of positions that are directly attached to each `user` object.  From here, take that *collection* of `positions` and try and find a *collection* of admins on that are attached to that collection and then find a `$position`.  (I think this is close to what it is trying to do...)

When you get to the inside of the loop and your `anchor` / `route`, you are asking the `anchor` to find an `id` on something that is likely either non-existent, or a collection again.

You have already passed in `admins` to this view. It would make sense to use that as your top level loop item, no?

**To fix**, use `admins` as the only loop item:

```
 @foreach ($admins as $position )
```

Comment: Dont forget the table layout quirks and the extra `@endforeach`

Comment: Yep.  And a few other things I suspect.  Didn't even see the extra `@endforeach` or `<tbody>`s till you edited.  Heh, which was your exact point in your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your Blade With

```
@foreach ($users as $positions)
@if(!empty($positions->admins)
@foreach ($positions->admins as $position )
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $position->id}}</td>
        <td>{{ $position->first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $position->last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $position->contact}}</td>
        <td>{{ $position->departments->department}}</td>
        <td>{{ $position->schoolpositions->school_position}}</td>
        <td>{{ $position->email}}</td>
        <th> <a href="{{action('DashboardController@edit',$position['id' =>$position->id])}} " class="btn btn-success">Edit </a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
</tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
@endif
@endforeach                                
</table>
```